# NPAPI Safari Windows

Tags: windows, safari, npapi

I have built NPAPI plugin that is loaded fine by Chrome, FF, and Safari browsers on Windows 7. However, I needed to duplicate the plugin to make it a different plugin (name). I was able, so far, to make Chrome and Firefox recognized the 2nd plugin (on about:plugins) using different name and mime-type and tested both plugins work as expected. But, on Safari (5.1.7) it doesn't work as expected. It seems only recognize the last plugin gets installed. If I uninstall the last plugin, it makes the first plugin (which is remained installed) working as expected. I monitored using Process Monitor and saw both plugins were being loaded. My debugging effort doesn't yield any clue. How does Safari identify each plugin installed on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

NPAPI plugins on windows identify the plugin based on the contents of the STRINGS resource in your .rc file; make sure you have a unique plugin name and different mimetypes and you should be fine.